# undefined method `permit' for "#<Flight:0xdb2b88c>":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Почему выскакивает данная ошибка?

```
Failure/Error:
       params.require(:flight).permit(:airline, :flight_number, :number_with_date,
         :flight_type, :code_shared, :departure_time, :arrival_time, :origin_apt,
         :destination_apt, :origin_id, :destination_id, :aircraft, :capacity_weight,
         :capacity_volume, :available, :update_status)

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `permit' for "#<Flight:0xdb2b88c>":String
     # ./app/controllers/api/v1/flights_controller.rb:50:in `flight_params'
     # ./app/controllers/api/v1/flights_controller.rb:30:in `create'
     in <module:Runner>'
     # ./spec/api/v1/flights_spec.rb:137:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

сама спека

```
describe 'POST /create' do
    let(:access_token) { create(:access_token) }
    let(:user) { User.find(access_token.resource_owner_id) }
    let(:flight) { create(:flight) }

    context 'authorized' do
      context 'with valid attributes' do
        before do
          user.update!(role: 'robot')
          post '/api/v1/flights', format: :json, access_token: access_token.token, flight: flight
        end

        it 'responses with 201' do
          expect(response.status).to eq 201
        end

        it 'creates new flight' do
          expect { response }.to change(Flight, :count).by 1
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Контроллер

```
class Api::V1::FlightsController < Api::V1::BaseController
  skip_before_action :doorkeeper_authorize!, only: [:index, :search, :show]
  before_action :set_flight, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
  authorize_resource

  def create
    @flight = Flight.create(flight_params)
    respond_with :api, :v1, @flight
  end

  private

  def set_flight
    @flight = Flight.find(params[:id])
  end

  def flight_params
    params.require(:flight).permit(:airline, :flight_number, :number_with_date,
      :flight_type, :code_shared, :departure_time, :arrival_time, :origin_apt,
      :destination_apt, :origin_id, :destination_id, :aircraft, :capacity_weight,
      :capacity_volume, :available, :update_status)
  end
end
```

Comment: Фабрики не нужны. Схема не нужна. А вот на какой запрос такое прилетело (из какой формы или JS), неплохо бы увидеть.

Comment: Добавил спеку которая падает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хорошие новости: контроллер правильный. Технически. Неправильные только спеки.

Дело в том, что вы пытаетесь передать в параметрах объект модели `Flight`. Не зная, как его передать по HTTP, тестофреймворк сделал `.to_s` (...наверное? Стоит проверить) и в итоге получил в `params[:flight]` строку `"#<Flight:0хШотатам>"`.

Починить это легко, просто думайте что передаёте. На уровне пользователя ActiveRecord ещё не существует, нужно делать наборы параметров (будь то форма, JSON или ещё что-нибудь). К примеру, с помощью `attributes_for` из FactoryGirl, который собирает хэшмап -- а его уже известно в каком виде отдавать по HTTP.

Comment: спасибо получилось. `post '/api/v1/flights', format: :json, access_token: access_token.token, flight: attributes_for(:flight)`